# Storing the return value of a function that returns a reference

Tags: c++

In the following code, I am having trouble understanding whether or not to declare `alg_marg` and `true_marg` as references and in particular why one behaves differently to the other.

```
int run_test(InfAlg& alg, FactorGraph& fg, vector<Factor>& exact_marg) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < fg.nrVars(); i++) {
        // true_marg declared as a reference
        TProb<Real>& true_marg = exact_marg[i].p();
        // alg_marg can't be declared as a reference or the code breaks later on - why?
        TProb<Real> alg_marg = alg.belief(fg.var(i)).p();
    }
}
```

The relevant function signatures from the doc are given as:

```
Factor dai::JTree::belief (const VarSet &vs) const virtual
const TProb<T>& p() const
TProb< >& p ()
```

The function signature of `p()` indicates that it returns a reference, so shouldn't I declare `alg_marg` as a reference?

Comment: `Factor dai::JTree::belief (const VarSet &vs) const virtual` is incorrect syntax. can you post your real code?

Comment: Sorry I copied that from the doc; it's not my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
alg.belief(fg.var(i))
```

This returns a `Factor` object that's a temporary that you immediately use `p()` on which returns a `TProb`. The temporary will be destroyed and (assuming whatever `p` returns is a member of `Factor`) will be gone too. Leaving you with a dangling reference.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. What is the correct way to handle this?